# Spring Aspect Not Called

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Given a Spring Boot application with

AspectJConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectJConfiguration {

}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class DataAccessExceptionAspect implements ThrowsAdvice {
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.acme.dao.*(..))", 
    throwing = "e")
    public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, 
        DataAccessException e) throws Throwable {

        // do something
        throw new AppSpecificCustomException();
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
package com.acme.dao;
// etc...

@Repository
public class WidgetDAO {
    @Autowired NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    // etc...

    public Widget getWidget(Long widgetId) {
        // etc...
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, paramMap, rowMapper);
    }
}
```

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject throws DataAccessException.

I would expect that when getWidget() is passed a widgetId that does not exist, that a DataAccessException (in particular EmptyResultDataAccessException) would be thrown and that the Aspect would catch it. The exception is thrown, but the aspect never sees it. I've tried changing the signature of the aspect to:

```
public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, 
        EmptyResultDataAccessException e) throws Throwable
```

and it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making 2 changes.

1) The aspect needs to be managed by Spring. Adding the @Component annotation solves this.

2) The pointcut was defined wrong. It should be com.acme.dao.WidgetDAO.*

```
@Component // @Component annotation is required
@Aspect
public class DataAccessExceptionAspect implements ThrowsAdvice {
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.acme.dao.WidgetDAO.*(..))", 
    throwing = "e")
    public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, 
        DataAccessException e) throws Throwable {

        // do something
        throw new AppSpecificCustomException();
    }
}
```